# Calculating position on scroll causes flash

Tags: jquery, css, position, absolute

For my project I need to re-calculate the position of an absolute element on scroll (can't be a fixed positioned one). The next function works fine but it causes a flickering/movement/flash of the element when scrolling – I assume it's related with this constant calculation.

I managed to completely fixed it on *Chrome* by adding this piece of code I found on another article: `background: url(null) fixed;`

But keeps happening on *Safari* and *iOS*. Is there a known way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

```js
function fix_close() {
  var c = $(window).scrollTop();
  var fixedClose = $('.close');
  fixedClose.css('position', 'absolute');
  fixedClose.css('top', c + 'px');
}
fix_close();

$(window).on('scroll', fix_close);
```

```css
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="close" href="/">Close</a>
```

Comment: Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @biberman OK. Added some more code in case it helps understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! But i see no flickering. Furthermore where is the next function and the constant calculation?

Comment: First jQuery function is for the calculation @biberman